# Create dynamic width labels in tableView cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

[image: check the design from here]

I want to create the design as shown in image. I mean the label has static height but dynamic width and it will automatically adjust in a row according to spacing. if the label can adjust in a same row then put it there otherwise if label width is more than the space left in row put label in next line.

The Problem is label count is also dynamic is should be any number (e.g. 5,8,7,9) So how can i adjust all bubble in a cell so that they can't overlap.

Is anyone help me to creating this view or suggest me any library etc.

Comment: Try to use UICollectionView instead of UITableView

Comment: Sorry, i am already using tableview and this is the design of single cell that i want. I can't change the entire design for this cell only.  Thanks for your revert

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired layout, by making use of collectioView, following are few steps you can follow to achieve the desired result.

1) Use collection view & Make sure you set the scroll direction to "Vertical" so that items are arranged as shown in your image file.

2) And in order to left align,use "UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout" refer link :
   https://github.com/mokagio/UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout

with these step  we have achieved same result in our application  and it looks something like this..

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: Thanks for your help i want same like you suggest. But is there any way to create it without using collection view because i want to show it in tableView cell